# Hide Home button on ActionBar Sherlock Actionbar extending Navigation Activity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock on my simple app and would like to hide the HOME button if the user is on the home/main activity. I understand how to do so with the setHomeButtonEnabled(false), however, I am extending a class that contains my navigation and has setHomeButtonEnabled(true) and I cannot seem to overwrite that setting in my main activity.

Thanks to @andy I am able to get rid of the icon, however, I cannot get rid of the < arrow. Any ideas?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: FWIW just a passing comment, re: "however, I am extending a class that contains my navigation and has setHomeButtonEnabled(true) and I cannot seem to overwrite that setting in my main activity." -- Could this be due to some sort of call ordering issue between when your subclass calls setHomeButtonEnabled vs. the base class? Perhaps add logging and see? I only comment as I am using setHomeButtonEnabled across a class hierarchy and it seems to work well. Best of luck.

Comment: @MikeRepass the oncreate() in my main activity doesn't overwrite the base somehow does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have found to do this is to not have this set on your baseActivity:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and then set it as you will for each activity that requires the menu:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 7):

With ActionBarSherlock just put this in your home/main activity onCreate() method:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks @andy, the Icon is Gone, however, the back arrow is still there. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Try to add setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)

Comment: this hides the icon but not hides the back arrow. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score -1):

Get the home button view and apply this

```
 mHomeButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```